# Is it possible to change the path of modules/themes installed using an installation profile?

Tags: 7, distributions, drush

I have a site which has a profile which downloads a number of modules using `drush make`. It adds the modules in the path /profiles/*profile_name*/modules.

Is it possible in the make file of the profile to change the path to where the modules and themes are put, so that they are then installed in sites/all/modules and sites/all/themes?

Comment: If you don't want your modules in profiles/modules, why not just put all of your make rules into a single top-level makefile, and convert your profile into a module? If you move your modules out of the profiles folder, you don't have a profile any more, so you might as well make it a module, no?

Comment: Doing this for a maintained distribution/install profile could result in running into edge-case bugs on upgrades. At the very least, be sure you move *all* modules to sites/all/modules, as the update processing is (sadly) affected by the module's path on disk, you do not want the relative order to change.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already installed the profile — no, you can't move modules by modifying make file. Profile's `.make` file is used only during installation process.

If you want to replace modules from `profiles/%PROFILE_NAME%/modules/` to `sites/all/modules` on already installed copy of Drupal, you can just replace files (with `mv` or something) and then run [`system_rebuild_module_data()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_rebuild_module_data/7) function to ask Drupal to update modules destination. With Drush:

```
drush eval "system_rebuild_module_data();"
```

For profile installation process — I really don't know why and don't know how to modify `.make` file. Maybe you can specify `'contrib_destination'` property for every project?

Comment: No its not for an already existing one.  It's a profile I'm working on and when it runs and installs I am wanting the modules in the sites/all/modules or sites/all/themes.  The openatrium.make file is D6.  Does this apply for D7 as well then?

Comment: Are you creating your own profile make file? How do you setup it via Drush? Maybe with this information we can solve the problem.

Comment: Yes I use drush.  I have a drush make file which downloads core and then the profile.  In this profile is another .make file which downloads all the modules, themes and libraries I need.

Comment: As I can see form [Drush Make source](http://drupalcode.org/project/drush.git/blob/refs/heads/master:/commands/make/make.project.inc#l410), all sub-projects are stored in build path of parent project. I can't see how to rewrite it. Maybe you should create an issue [here](http://drupal.org/project/issues/drush?component=Make).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what the `[destination]` is for? Take a look into the [openatrium.make](http://drupalcode.org/project/openatrium.git/blob/7dc09cfa6ccc2225983a3861f787889201c3e1f5:/openatrium.make) file

Comment: I believe this only works for library items, and not for projects.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using `system_rebuild_module_data` (mentioned in another answer here), you can use contributed module "[Registry Rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild)". That module integrates with Drush via the `Drush RR` command.

Basically what you do is to (1) just move your modules to another directory, and (2) Registry Rebuild will then rebuild the system table to get the modules in the right place.

I first learned/discovered it via [DrupalEasy Podcast #133](http://drupaleasy.com/podcast/2014/06/drupaleasy-podcast-133-top-secret-drupal-capital-camp-gov-days), which further explains how this module / drush cmd can be used.

Comment: The question was: is it possible (on Drush Make level) to place profile modules NOT into profile folder and the honest answer was: **no**.