# Changing the module path on custom install profile

Tags: installation, distributions, drush

I would like to have the profile install the modules I list in my profile `.make` to `sites/all/modules/contrib` instead of in the profile directory `profiles/my_sweet_profile/modules/contrib` is there any way to do this without having to use a script to copy the modules, and then rebuilding the drupal registry?

I have read [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28698/changing-the-path-of-modules-installed-using-an-installation-profile) DA post, but the answers contained pertain to the more canonized distribution profiles (OpenAtrium). I am not going to be rerunning this installation profile on the same site, so there is no need for me to preserve the initial structure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get an example in Videola profile:
https://github.com/Videola/videola/blob/master/videola_starter.make - main make file which downloads only profile from github.

Then see main make file with all the modules: https://github.com/Videola/videola/blob/master/videola.make which shows you an example of what you want to do.

```
projects[admin][subdir] = "contrib"
```

Comment: This path is relative to the install profile, so it still installs modules in ``/profiles/my_profile/modules/contrib``. What I am looking for is a way to install the modules in ``sites/all/modules``